# Call async methods from Dispatcher.Invoke()?

Tags: .net, wpf, async-await, dispatcher

Can this kind of code bring trouble (e.g. deadlocks) or will it work as intended:

```
void CalledFromAnotherThread()
{
   Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DoUiStuff)
}

async Task DoUiStuff()
{
    await DoAsyncStuff();
}
```

When I am not awaiting DoUiStuff at all, should I make it return void then?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why use `Dispatcher.Invoke` at all instead of `await someBackgroundJob(); Update(); await DoAsyncStuff();`?  That `Invoke` runs on the UI thread, so yes, you can use asynchronous calls that will resume on the UI thread. You can avoid all that complexity though by not using `Invoke()`. You can break the calling async method into separate async operations that run before and after updating the UI

Comment: If you want to report progress from deep inside another thread/task, you can use the `IProgress<>` interface. Check [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the method CalledFromAnotherThread is a callback, so i have no control over it, is just passively gets called. I just need to update the UI when the callback is called and some of the update operations are slow by itself so they also should run as async.

Comment: In that case use `IProgress<T>`. This will keep UI code outside the async code and won't tie you to one specific desktop stack. You can pass any information you want as the payload, not just progress information

Comment: `the method CalledFromAnotherThread is a callback,` you can use a TaskCompletionSource to convert that callback to a task. This would allow you to use it in other scenarios too, not just notifying a UI

Comment: Besides that, be careful with using `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. It will create a new Dispatcher in case the current thread does not yet have a Dispatcher associated with it. Better use the `Dispatcher` of the UI element that should be updated, or at least `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Comment: `IProgress<T>` has nothing to do with the question and won't help the OP. That's simply a design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to avoid calling `Dispatcher.Invoke` altogether. This couples frontend and backend code and results in more complex code. I'd try to break the operations on parts that work on the background, await them with `await` and perform any UI modifications in between.

From the comments, it looks like `CalledFromAnotherThread` is a callback. Callbacks and events can be converted to tasks using [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-7.0), eg :

```
async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    var tcs=new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    _whatever.MyCallBack= ok=>{
        if(ok){
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        }
        else {
            tcs.SetException(...something...);
        }
    });
    _whatever.StartLongJob();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can await `DoSomethingAsync` async now, like any other asynchronous call.

```
await DoSomethingAsync();
DoUiStuff();
await DoOtherAsyncStuff();
```

Comment: This answer completely misses the point of the question. The OP has a callback invoked on a background thread and needs to do something in the UI in response. This is WPF. UI changes have to be invoked on the UI thread or exceptions will be thrown. You can't avoid that this way and you can't avoid use of the `Dispatcher` at all when that is the case unless you're using a strict MVVM pattern and only invoking `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`. We don't know what the OP is doing in `DoUIStuff` but we should assume it needs to happen on the UI thread.

Comment: @PeterMoore no it doesn't. I've worked with WPF since it came out, and yes, using async/await properly avoids cross-thread problems. No, using INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't help because it still runs on the thread that raised the event. MVVM frameworks like Caliburn and MvvmLight had to jump through some hooks to emulate asynchronous operations.

Comment: @PeterMoore have you actually tried using async/await properly? In one case I used it to search for air travels from airlines (GDSs actually) using heavy SOAP calls asynchronously, parse the results, generate view models, display them in a grid and save the actual responses. That required several async operations with UI updates between them. Never used Dispatcher

Comment: @PeterMoore `We don't know what the OP is doing in DoUIStuff but we should assume it needs to happen on the UI thread.` and yes, after that `await` execution returns to the original synchronization context, the UI thread. So `DoUIStuff` does happen on the UI thread

Comment: You may think you're helping by suggesting a radically different approach than what the OP is doing, but they already said "I have no control over [the callback]". You don't actually help anyone when you ignore the question asked just so you can give your personal opinion on an unrelated topic. Not everyone is lucky enough to be able to personally dictate all the conditions under which they are asked to work.